# "$q defered.promise is not a function" error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have defined the following `IndexMangeService` service in hope to pre-check the input parameter and return a promise after a `$http` request.

```
merchant.service('IndexManageService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
        this.getObjectIdByUrl = function(url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (!(/.*ababab.com.*/.test(url))){
                deferred.reject("url not correct");
            }else{
                $http.get('/api/getObjectIdByUrl?url='+url).then(
                    function success(response){
                        var json = response.data;
                        if(json.status == 0){
                            deferred.resolve({id: json.data.id});
                        }else{
                            deferred.reject(json.msg);
                        }
                    },
                    function failed(response){
                        deferred.reject(response.status);
                    }
                )
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        };
        this.getUrlByObjectId = function(id){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get("/api/getUrlByObjectId?id="+id).then(
                function success(response){
                    var json = response.data;
                    if(json.status == 0){
                        deferred.promise({
                            url: "http://cdnimg.gifmiao.com/"+json.data.url
                        })
                    }else{
                        deferred.reject(json.msg);
                    }
                },
                function failed(response){
                    deferred.reject("failed" + response.status);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise();
        }
    }]);
```

But those two methods from `IndexManageService` keeps showing the following error message:

[image: deferred.promise is not a function]

What am I doing wrong using $q in AngularJS?

Comment: Simply remove brackets '()' from deferred.promise()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your error said, promise in not a function.

In `getUrlByObjectId()` function, change:

```
return deferred.promise();
```

To

```
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Have upvote this, but if you can edit the answer and include the other typo,  should accept this as an answer, thank you.

Comment: @armnotstrong As you already fixed the typo in the code of your question, I would suggest act as if it had never existed ;P

Comment: That's smart ;P

Answer (score 2):

I just replace promise() with promise in your getUrlByObjectId() method. and it will be working.

- See more at: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/angularjs-deferred-promises-basic-understanding/#promise-in-angularjs

**Deferred Object:**

> Deferred is an object which expose the promise. It has  mainly three
>   methods resolve(), reject(), and notify(). Deferred returns promise
>   object. When Deferred completes, You call methods either resolve(),
>   reject(), and notify() . It calls callback register to either
>   resolve(), reject(), or notify() according to how it has completed.

```
merchant.service('IndexManageService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    this.getObjectIdByUrl = function (url) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (!(/.*ababab.com.*/.test(url))) {
            deferred.reject("url not correct");
        } else {
            $http.get('/api/getObjectIdByUrl?url=' + url).then(
                    function success(response) {
                        var json = response.data;
                        if (json.status == 0) {
                            deferred.resolve({id: json.data.id});
                        } else {
                            deferred.reject(json.msg);
                        }
                    },
                    function failed(response) {
                        deferred.reject(response.status);
                    }
            )
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    this.getUrlByObjectId = function (id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("/api/getUrlByObjectId?id=" + id).then(
                function success(response) {
                    var json = response.data;
                    if (json.status == 0) {
                        deferred.promise({
                            url: "http://cdnimg.gifmiao.com/" + json.data.url
                        })
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject(json.msg);
                    }
                },
                function failed(response) {
                    deferred.reject("failed" + response.status);
                }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your promise usage could be such that you would avoid the issue altogether. You don't need a deferred object at all!

```
merchant.service('IndexManageService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  this.getObjectIdByUrl = function(url) {
    if (!(/.*ababab.com.*/.test(url))){
      return $q.reject(new Error("url not correct"));
    }
    return getAPI('/getObjectIdByUrl?url=' + url).then(function(data) { 
      return "http://cdnimg.gifmiao.com/" + data.url;
    });
  };
  this.getUrlByObjectId = function(id){
    return getAPI('getUrlByObjectId?id=' + id).then(function(data) {
      return data.id;
    });
  }
  function getApi(url) {
    return $http.get("/api" + url).then(function(res) {
      if(res.data.status !== 0) throw new Error(res.msg);
      return res.data.data;
    }, function(res) { throw new Error(res.status); });
  }
}]);
```